# How to add a min value to an input on the condition another input's specific option is selected?

Tags: reactjs

Trying to add a min value to an input field, but only if another field has a certain option selected.

```
              <input
                type="number"
                className="HeroParameterFeedNumberInputLarge"
                name="durationAmount"
                value={parameterForm.durationAmount}
                onChange={handleParameterChange}
              />

              <select
                type="text"
                className="HeroParameterDropdownInput"
                name="durationType"
                value={parameterForm.durationType}
                onChange={handleParameterChange}
              >
                <option value="minutes">minutes</option>
                <option value="hours">hours</option>
                <option value="days">days</option>
              </select>
```

Tried adding the min value on the input, but it remains even if hours or days is selected.

```
              <input
                type="number"
                className="HeroParameterFeedNumberInputLarge"
                name="durationAmount"
                min='5'
                value={parameterForm.durationAmount}
                onChange={handleParameterChange}
              />

              <select
                type="text"
                className="HeroParameterDropdownInput"
                name="durationType"
                value={parameterForm.durationType}
                onChange={handleParameterChange}
              >
                <option value="minutes">minutes</option>
                <option value="hours">hours</option>
                <option value="days">days</option>
              </select>
```

Comment: Please provide a  [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try a conditional setting of the `min` property

```
<input
  type="number"
  className="HeroParameterFeedNumberInputLarge"
  name="durationAmount"
  min={parameterForm.durationType === 'minutes' ? 5 : undefined}
  value={parameterForm.durationAmount}
  onChange={handleParameterChange}
  />
```

Comment: Amazing!! That worked, thanks! It still allows you to have a  < 5 input though if you have 'hours' or 'days' selected first, and then switch to 'minutes'. How could I revert the input back to >= 5 logic if this happens?

Comment: @ryan, since the component is controlled, you will have to change the `parameterForm.durationAmount` when the `durationType` changes. You could, alternatively, style the component to indicate that it is invalid, through the `:invalid` css pseudoselector.

Comment: Trying to go the css pseudoselector route, but having trouble getting it to work. Am i correct to think that I just need to add the pseudoselector in the css file, and anything that doesn't meet the min requirement should be triggering it? `input:invalid {
    border: 2px solid red;
    color: red;
  }`